# Reset mysql init_connect values

Tags: mysql

I executed an incorrect `SQL` command:

```
SET GLOBAL init_connect='SET CHARACTER SET=utf-8';
```

Now, when I try and run a script that connects to this database, I get the following error: `_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')`.

How would I reset the global `init_connect` values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE "init%"
SET GLOBAL init_connect='';
```